# error fatal en MongoClient

Tags: php, mongodb, localhost

buenas tardes tengo este error cuando voy a abrir el proyecto en el navegador por localhost y me sale este error no se si este error ya esta solucionado en otro lado de ser así dejar post para ver

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\mongoPHP\dbconnection.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\mongoPHP\dbconnection.php(28): DBConnection->__construct() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\mongoPHP\Create_users.php(4): DBConnection::instantiate() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\mongoPHP\dbconnection.php on line 16

dbconnection.php

```
<?php
class DBConnection{
const HOST='localhost';
const PORT=27017;
const DBNAME='Foro';

private static $instance;
public $connection;
public $database;

private function __construct(){
    $connectionString=sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d',DBConnection::HOST,DBConnection::PORT);

    try{
        $this->connection=new MongoClient($connectionString);
        $this->database=$this->connection->selectDB(DBConnection::DBNAME);

    }catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Create_users.php

```
<?php
require('dbconnection.php');

$mongo=DBConnection::instantiate();
$collection=$mongo->getCollection('users');

 $user=array(
array(
    'nombre'=>'andrey andy',
    'nombreusuario'=>'andrey',
    'password'=>md5('andrey09'),

),
array(
    'nombre'=>'andy',
    'nombreusuario'=>'andy',
    'password'=>md5('andy09'),

)
);

foreach($users as $user){
    try{
        $collection->insert($user);
    }catch(MongoCursoException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
echo 'Usuario creado exitosamente';



  ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP y de controlador de Mongo estás usando?